# Android: how do I tell my activity to start new activity from my service?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, download

I have a service that is, among other things, downloading images from internet. When this is done I want to show this image in a custom Activity that has a dialog theme. But I only want to use this pop up if the app is running, otherwise I just want to create a notification.

But I get an exception when I try to start an activity from my service and i feel that maybe this isn't the right way to do it?

It says:

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

So my question is if this is the right way to do this by setting that flag or how should I get my downloaded image from my service to an activity. Can I in some way tell an activity to start a new activity from my service class?

Comment: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar is this the best solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using Broadcast Receiver is better option for you.

Add Below Method in Service and call this method when image Download Complete.

```
private void updateMyActivity(Context context) {
     if(MainActivity.activityStatusFlag){
        //update the activity if activityStatusFlag=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent("mUpdateActivity");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);        
     }else{
         //display notification if activityStatusFlag=false;
     }
}
```

In Activity Add Following Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public static boolean activityStatusFlag= false; 
        //define this variable to check if activity is running or not.

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();   
        activityStatusFlag = true;
        this.getApplicationContext().
        registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter("mUpdateActivity"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        activityStatusFlag = false;  
        this.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Display Popup or update Activity
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is how I thought it should be. Thank you! I added intent.putExtra(); in the updateMyActivity() method and then got it from the onRecieve() on the broadcastreceiver. Worked out great!